# javascript make child function stop parent function

Tags: javascript

Hello I am currently executing a child function from a parent
However if something particular happens I want the child function to stop the rest of the parent function to stop executing

How do I do this without using a return ?

The child function is a module

Main.js

```
console.log("Beginning") 
const func_import = require("/module.js")
func_import()
console.log("not to be executed in certain cases")
```

module.js

```
module.exports = async() => {
   console.log("something")
}
```

I tried to use a simple return value
However this just returned an undefined even after I used await

Comment: You can use exceptions.

Comment: There's no direct way. You can return a value that the caller checks, or you can throw an exception.

Comment: Are you operating in a NodeJS environment or in the browser.

Comment: You declare the function `async`, but it's not actually doing anything asynchronously. Is the real function asynchronous? You'll need to use `await` if you want the caller to wait for it.

Comment: Yes the real function is Async

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but very, very strange. You can throw an error in the child:

```
module.exports = () => {
    if (condition) {
        throw new Error();
    }
}
```

This will cause the parent (and each of *its* parents) to stop executing at the point of the function:

```
console.log("Beginning") 
const func_import = require("/module.js")
func_import() // <-- stops here
console.log("not to be executed in certain cases")
```

Don't do this. Errors should be used for exceptional circumstances (there's a reason they're called "exceptions"), not for simple control flow. Return a value instead.

```
module.exports = () => {
    // other code
    return condition;
}
```

```
console.log("Beginning") 
const func_import = require("/module.js")
const condition = func_import();
if (!condition) {
    console.log("not to be executed in certain cases")
}
```